# When I host the code navigation bar is not showing properly, but when I run it in pycharm it works fine. Is anyone know what is the problem?

Tags: django

[this is when I run this code at pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZLCH.png)

[this is when I host the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86WS.png)

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.